# Spacing on sprites using compass not working?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sprite

I'm currently working on a project where im using several icons in the sidebar (You can have a sneak peak over here: http://epen.herokuapp.com )

The problem is that on Retina screens some of the icons manages to get 1 pixel of the icon above / below causing there to be unwanted pixels.

To fix this i could simply use the sprite spacing i figured but i cant seem to get it working doing the following:

```
$base-sprite-spacing: 20px;
$base-sprite-dimensions: true;
@import "base/*.png";
@include all-base-sprites;
```

Any suggestions to what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you've already sorted this, but the spacing issue is caused by the inclusion of the word 'sprite'. Should just be $base-spacing: 20px; so it matches the name of your folder.

Comment: It would help to post the meat of the article in your answer, as links tend to break.